# How to pass data to IFTTT WebHook?

Tags: google-sheets, ifttt

I have a task to add row into Google Sheet when WebHook received. Now I'm trying to setup IFTTT but have some problem
It says that I should use URL like `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/{my_key}` and that is ok I can do it. But it needs to send some data in request and the only way my system can do it appends it to query string like `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/{my_key}?name1=Alex&name2=Helen`

But IFTTT doesn't see my data. it says that it can see data in attached JSON but I can't use JSON.

So is there any way to pass my data to IFTT in a query string or shell I forgot IFTTT and investigate how to connect directly to Google Sheet?

Answer (score 23):

IFTTT Maker webhooks can only take data with keys of "value1", "value2", and "value3". Try sending it with:

```
https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/{my_key}?value1=Alex&value2=Helen
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://bitly.com/ which will shorten and convert the query params to a path param. That worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

First thing first, Web hooks are designed to accept data using `POST` method only and here you are sending data using `GET`, which is obviously not going to work, i guess.

Second, in order to get it work, one way is to use `cURL` request and send your JSON in Body with `POST` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change these request. I can change it only if I will add some middleware but it will increase project cos t:( So is there any way to get data from GET request to google sheet?

Comment: GET request work just as well as POST.  As @silvamerica says, just provide value1 to value3 as query parameters.  What you can't do is use different parameter names (or additional parameters).